# What would be the result of the collision of two down quarks?

Tags: particle-physics, collision, quarks

Even if we can't have single quarks in nature because of the charge colour, what would be the result of the collision of two down quarks at high velocities (0,99% c) at high energies, like the ones of LHC proton's collision..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

99% of the speed of light generates a Lorentz factor of only

$$ \gamma = \left[ 1 - (.99)^2 \right]^{-1/2} \approx 7 $$

which means that you have only about 14 times the mass of a down-quark to make additional particles. The [PDG puts the bare mass of the down quark](http://pdglive.lbl.gov/Rsummary.brl?nodein=Q123&exp=Y) in the neighborhood of 5 MeV, so $14 \times 5\,\mathrm{MeV} = 70\,\mathrm{MeV}$ isn't enough energy to create any pair except an electron--positrons.

So, here are some possible outcomes (taking into account that you *must* be doing baryon collisions and just looking at cases where you have collisions between constituent down quarks

- Elastic collision. Your baryons go in and come out with different moment but otherwise unchanged.
- Electron-positron pair creation, but the baryons still come out unchanged.
- (If you have at least on nucleus rather than a bare nucleon in the input state) nuclear excitation.

In other words: **nothing much**. That is a result of your specifying a very low energy regime.

Some things you *don't have enough energy* to do:

- Muon--antimuon creation.
- Meson creation (not even a $\pi^0$).
- Nucleon excitation (assuming a nucleon or nuclear beam).
- Most meson excitations (assuming a meson beam for at least one of the quarks)

---

BTW--Particle physicists rarely talk about speed in this kind of context, because most speeds approach $c$ (often very closely). Instead we generally talk about energy and/or momentum. The exception when we do talk about speeds is when we are using Cerenkov detectors.

Comment: I were wanting to say at high energies, like the ones of LHC proton's collision..

Comment: p=mv and that's why I referred to speed...

Comment: Momentum is *not* linearly related to velocity in a relativistic regime. You can write $p = \gamma m v$ if you insist on that form, but as I said particle physicist don't reach for velocity first to understand kinematics; simply because it is more algebraically complicated to use velocity than it is to simply rely on the four-momentum.

Comment: So what would be the result of the collision at high energies..?

Comment: Almost all the things you get with high energy baryon collisions, of course. The only exceptions would be really pure Drell-Yan reactions and other things that you cant have without quark--antiquark annihilation.

Comment: I read in a paper (doesn't remember the name...) that the result of the collision were a up quark and a down one and an electron/positron and a neutrino

Comment: That is one of many (*very* many) possible outcomes if there is enough energy. Moreover because of the neutrino we know that you are looking at a weak scattering event at low energy (far below the $Z$ mass), so it is not a very likely one.